# how can i find an 90 angle relative to another angle

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

Say i have a line pointing 35 degree, and i want to draw a line on that line and produce a 90 degree angle how can i fine the angle of the second line?

image would explain better.[image]

So in the upper image we have a line that has 0 degree, while another line intersects it at 90 degree - and we already know its a 90.

in the lower image a line is at 30-40 degrees, how do i find the angle of the second line ?

in javascript if possible.

Thanks

Comment: If line A is at 35 degrees then line B needs to be at (35 + 90) degrees, or more generally you could code the calculation as `B = (A + 90) % 360`. What about that are you having trouble with? Or are you able to calculate the required angle but not sure about how to calculate actual end points for such a line?

Comment: Perpendicular slopes http://www.purplemath.com/modules/slope2.htm

Comment: @nnnnn there no issue , i am just not good with math and your answer works perfectly You can see it : http://jsfiddle.net/chLTK/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that angle A is 35 degrees then angle B just needs to be 35 + 90. Allowing for "wrap-around" past 360 degrees for cases where angle A is greater than 270 degrees you can do this:

```
var B = (A + 90) % 360;
```

That way if A is, say, 290 degrees you'll get B as 20 rather than 380.